# Работа с выводом строк

Tags: java, строки

Есть контейнер со словами уже отсортированный по алфавиту `List<String>`, нужно написать метод который бы выводил слова с красной строки, которые начинаются с новой буквы, а последнее слово заканчивалось точкой, например:

Output:

```
  арбуз, арбуз, арбуз, арбуз,
арбуз, арбуз, арбуз, арбуз,
арбуз, арбуз, арбуз, арбуз,
  банан, банан, банан, банан,
банан, банан, банан, банан,
банан,
  виноград, виноград, виноград, виноград,
виноград, виноград, виноград,
  груша, груша, груша.
```

Это то что я сделал.

```
private void print(List<Word> words) {
    char mark = ',';
    Character temp = words.get(0).toString().charAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        Character c = words.get(i).toString().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

        if ((i == words.size() - 1)){
            mark = '.';
        }

        if (!c.equals(temp)) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("  " + words.get(i) + mark + " ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("  " + words.get(i) + "" + mark + "  ");
        }
        temp = words.get(i).toString().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

У меня не получилось. =(

Comment: Покажите, что вы уже сделали, иначе Ваш вопрос не представляет полезности и возможо будет закрыт.

Comment: Поясните "не получилось"

Comment: Какой-то странный output. Надо выводить не более 4 слов в строку, а каждая новая буква начинает новый абзац?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Так как я показал в output не получилось сделать

Comment: @Qwertiy ну чтобы было видно, что новое слово с красной строки начинается, поэтому нужно вывести не более 4 слова в строку

Comment: @Fairkhan, мой вопрос был вызван тем, что вы недостаточно раскрыли что именно у вас не получается. То что у вас не получилось и так понятно. Но что именно не получилось?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб они у меня просто все слова с одной буквой выводятся с новой строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю на сколько правильно, но у меня работает :)

```
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = initArray();
    StringBuilder resultString = new StringBuilder();
    char prevFirstChar;
    char currFirstChar;
    int countInRow = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        //флаг был ли перенос
        boolean isN = false;
        //текущий и предыдущий первый символ
        if ((i - 1) < 1) {
            prevFirstChar = arrayList.get(i).charAt(0);
        } else {
            prevFirstChar = arrayList.get((i - 1)).charAt(0);
        }
        currFirstChar = arrayList.get(i).charAt(0);
        //проверка на кол-во слов в строке
        if (countInRow == 4) {
            resultString.append("\n");
            isN = true;
            countInRow = 1;
        } else {
            countInRow++;
        }
        //сравненеие первых символов
        if (currFirstChar == (prevFirstChar)) {
            resultString.append(arrayList.get(i));
        } else {
            if (!isN) {
                resultString.append("\n");
                countInRow = 1;
            }
            resultString.append(arrayList.get(i));
        }
        //проверка на точку
        if (arrayList.get(i).contains(".")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Result:\n" + resultString.toString());
```

Comment: Он должен ставить запятые, а когда конец массива поставить точку, а не запятую, а у вас он проверяет на наличие точки.

Comment: @Fairkhan ну тогда будет просто убрать последнюю проверку, и добавить ещё if, который проверит последний ли это элемент, если да ставит точку, если нет - запятую

Comment: Ну вот чтобы обозначить красную строку нужно чтобы вначале пробелы стояли, а если перенос слов одно и той же буквы там уже ненужно, если новая буква то снова пробелы.

Comment: Все спасибо, получилось ! =)